# TeXstudio: How to put already written text in brackets and set the cursor at opening bracket?

Tags: texstudio, brackets, shortcut

No MWE, for this pertains to the editor itself.
I use TeXstudio mainly, but have briefly used TeXmaker a little.

When I write LaTeX documents, I *very* often find myself writing some text only to realise later, I want that text to be bold, italic, or in some command.

I am looking for an all-purpose way of marking text and then, preferably, some keyboard shortcut to encapsulates the marked text in curly brackets and put the cursor **before** the first bracket - so that I can type a command before the text or whatever markdown I need.

Marking text and then pressing keys for beginning parenthesis places the cursor at the end of the text, not even at outside the ending parenthesis. So in essence I am asking if it is possible to change what beginning curly bracket with marked text does in TeXstudio.

Comment: what version of TXS are you using on what system?

Comment: TeXstudio: 2.10.8 (hg 5802:5ee1d048e556)
Using Qt Version 5.5.1, compiled with Qt 5.5.1 R ; 

OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia. Nordic "hardware" keyboard with Danish keyboard settings.

Comment: have you read section 4.5 in the TXS manual? maybe you can create a macro for your purposes.

Comment: I have read about macros before and shortcuts, but the only macro I have ever created was a lot simpler, so I didn't know if this thing could be done with macro. I hoped it maybe would be "just" changing some built-in function in TXS, so telling it to place cursor somewhere else than it does now. But it seems it is indeed a fair but more complex than that.

Comment: The shortcuts for fonts automatically warp the selected text in curly brackets. For example select the text and `cmd+I` (or whatever the equivalent on your os is) will produce `normal text \textit{selected text} normal text`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this question is asked at the right place, but nonetheless I found it interesting to try. Apparently you can add custom TeXstudio macros. In the main menu, click `Macros > Edit macros...`. At the right you can name your macro appropriately. The `Abbreviation` and `Trigger` option are not needed for this. The `Type` must be set to `Script`. Now you can add the following content:

```
%SCRIPT
c = cursor
var arr = new Array('\\{',c.selectedText(),'}');
str = arr.join('')
c.insertText(str)
c.moveTo(c.lineNumber(),c.columnNumber()-str.length+1)
```

Now you can achieve what you want with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. I think you can even assign your own shortcut in the `Options > Configure TeXstudio...` menu.

**Explanation**
`c=cursor` This line declares a cursor object named `c`
`var arr = new Array('\\{',c.selectedText(),'}');` This line defines an array that starts with `\{` and ends with `}`. In between it places the text that is currently selected in the editor. The second `\` is needed to escape, because it is an active character.
`str = arr.join('')` This line joins the array in *one* string (using the empty string `''` as delimiter) and places it in `str`.
`c.insertText(str)` This line simply inserts the text in `str`.
`c.moveTo(c.lineNumber(),c.columnNumber()-str.length+1)` This line places the cursor to the position right after the `\`. The function `c.moveTo` takes two arguments, the first being the line number, and the second the column number. For the column number I used the current column number, minus the length of `str`, plus one to account for the `\`.

Comment: I knew about creating macros, and chancing/adding keyboard shortcuts but the level of complexity concerning the "selected text" is too high for me to figure out for myself. So I would have had no idea how to code anything like the snippet you wrote. I will try with that!
I guess I should have prefaced my question with that maybe this is _too_ integral to how TeXstudio has decided its editor should be, and I would live just fine if there is no "easy" solution, especially if this solution lies beyond what is TeXstudio functionality and as such should now have been asked here.

Comment: this script is very specific to `{`. is it possible to make it more abstract, to have brackets or parentheses as well? or does one have to create scripts for each case?

Comment: @naphaneal I think it would be possible to generalize it for more characters, but that would be at the cost of usability. Personally I would create such scripts for each case, of course with an additional variable for the opening and closing character.

Comment: It works. Only "problem" now is that I would like it to be set to the same shortcut as a normal { (or }, anyone of them). For my keyboard, that's AltGr+7 or AltGr+0. But I cannot add use AltGr as a manually set shortcut. Yes it works with Alt+Ctrl of course, but that's one more key. I realize that the use of AltGr for special signs are a country, hardware and system depended issue, so I do not automatically expect TXS to have a solution. But would be cool if it had.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with that. It is possible to use `Alt+7` but `Alt Gr+7` doesn't work for me either. If you consider your question as answered, would you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: I marked it as answered, but one small caveat: Your macro creates \{} - but if I for instance am typing a long equation with long subscript words, I only need {} and the correct cursor placement - not a \. But if I remove one of the \'s in the code, the remaining one turns green (so I assume its a different class) and the macro then gives {} but with the cursor placed inside the first bracket.

Comment: For that case you can remove both the backslashes and remove the `+1` in the last line. See edit.

Answer (score 7):

If the command that you want to insert is recognized and offered by the TXS autocompleter, the canonical solution is to

i) highlight the part you want to be enclosed in brackets,

ii) type the command (with the command appearing in the autocompleter), and then

iii) pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: gif]

**Additional note:**

- if there is only one word you want to highlight in step (i), you can just use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut.
- as @samcarter mentioned, having font styles like `\textbf`, `\emph`, `\textit` are already available as keyboard shortcuts. Highlight the desired content to be emphasized, then apply the keyboard shortcut, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> etc.

It also works for sub-/superscripts with their associated keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).

[image: gif2]

- If the command you selected has multiple arguments/placeholders, your selected text will be entered into the first placeholder (see gif).
- the latest version is 2.12.10, do update if it's available as an option to you.

Comment: It's very unintuitive that the text disappears but is actually still "saved" within TXS and will reappear when you are done typing the command. But good to know about this functionality. It exists for simple font styles, I wanted a way so it could work for all font styles or other non-command changes, like sub/super scripting. The latter has buttons too, yes, but I would like to do this without too much mouse work. As opposed to marking and writing commands, it does not seem that highlighting, and then typing ^ saves the text.

Comment: @snowzky It works for subscripts and superscripts too when using their keyboard shortcuts. I'll edit my post to add that in. There's no mouse work at all.

Comment: OT: @Troy what tool did you use for the animation?

Comment: @naphaneal ScreenToGif with ffmpeg.