# Overleaf shortcut: Put already written text in brackets

Tags: overleaf, shortcut

I am looking for a shortcut which puts already written text in curly brackets.
I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439872/texstudio-how-to-put-already-written-text-in-brackets-and-set-the-cursor-at-ope) but it doesn't work for Overleaf. I thought that I once have read something similar in an article but didn't find it anymore.

Can anyone help?

I appreciate your answers/ comments!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this article](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/overleaf-keyboard-shortcuts/qykqfvmxdnjf)

Comment: thanks @JouleV. In this article I only read about putting text in bold text or italicise text. Do you know maybe how to put it only in curly brackets?`

Comment: That article is by a developer of Overleaf, so I doubt if there are some other shortcuts. Anyway, I _never_ use shortcuts on Overleaf, and that is no big deal...

Comment: There is no shortcut to do this on Overleaf at the moment (I'm on support staff there) - sorry about that. But I'll register an internal feature request for this, thanks!

Comment: Hey @walszje, thank you for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no shortcut to do this on Overleaf at the moment (I'm on support staff there) - sorry about that. But I've registered an internal feature request for this, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you specifically want curly braces {} there is a workaround. It is based on the fact that you can italicise selected text, and that the LaTeX notation used includes {}.

1. Mark the text => `no selected no`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>  => `no \textit{selected} no`
3. Remove the added `\textit` => `no {selected} no`

For step 2 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> works similarily.

Step 3 can also be done with a sequence of key-strokes if you like... (I'm now using `|` to show where the cursor is in each step.)

1. Mark the text => no `selected` no
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>  => no \textit{selected}`|` no
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>  => no \textit`|`{selected} no
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>  =>  no \ `textit`{selected} no
5. <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> =>  no \ `|`{selected} no
6. <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> =>  no `|`{selected} no

This works for multiline selections even if it contains matching {} already. If there is an unmatched { it will fail on step 3, but you can handle it manually as before.

Mission accomplished!

**EDIT:** Instead of selecting the last character (using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>) in step 5, it's easier to just backspace twice. I noticed that sometimes the revised step 3 isn't working so I suggest doing it "manually" as in the first case. If you want automation, my [second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517786) is probably 
better.

### References

This answer was inspired by [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509708) and the [overleaf hotkey document](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/overleaf-keyboard-shortcuts/qykqfvmxdnjf).

Comment: Welcome!! Excellent answer. Ah, I hate doing steps 3.4 and 3.5, it is so annoying!

Comment: @manooooh Thanks! I simplified step 3.5 a bit, but I think we can agree that [my new answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517786/201980) is better. Have a look! I also noticed that you edited the reference I gave to that other answer. I did mean the [specific revision](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/509708/2) in case it ever changes. Was there a problem with that link or did you just prefer linking to the answer itself?

Answer (score 0):

Using `|` to show where the cursor is in each step:

1. Mark the text => abc `selected` xyz
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  => abc `|` xyz
3. Write `{`  => abc {`|`} xyz
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> =>  abc {selected`|`} xyz

This may be an obvious solution, but I actually didn't think of it until I gave the [more complex answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517781) and belive it is worh spelling out (though not specific to TeX at all).

For step 3, Overleaf will add the closing bracket in most cases. It works for `[` and `$` too. For `(` you easily add the closing `)` yourself at step 4.

This works for multiline selections even if it contains brackets already. The only drawback is that it "destroys" any text already in the copy buffer.

I still think having a hotkey dedicated for encapsulating selected text is a good idea (I will try to suggest it again to Overleaf), and since this method is not depending on what the selected text is, this could be used to create these shortcuts in an external hotkey tool:

- '$' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>$</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>),
- '(' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>),
- '[' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>),
- '{' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>).

Note: Currently Overleaf have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> already taken for indentation, but there is <kbd>TAB</kbd> to do the same.

### References

This answer was inspired by [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517781) and the [overleaf hotkey document](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/overleaf-keyboard-shortcuts/qykqfvmxdnjf).

Answer (score -1):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>), then change `\textit{blabla}`.